# No "from" address specified in neither the specified in neither the given options nor the default options

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, react

So I already went through this query, but I still couldn't get my doubt solved. Be it any Blockchain Dapp, the same error is coming for me.
I used the marriage certificate and kickstart examples.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you explain what do you want, what are you doing to achieve this, and what do you get instead of desired result?

Answer (score 0):

In your DApp you are probably calling some of those Web3 API functions that do publish transactions to blockchain (e.g. [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)), or some non read-only functions of some smart contracts.  And you probably didn't provide value for `from` parameter, i.e. you didn't tell what private key to use to sign the transaction.

As long as every transaction has to be signed by some private key before being published into blockchain, you transactions cannot be published, and thus you get error message.

Regarding your code, your probably just don't have any accounts.

Comment: Here-in is a snippet of my code

Comment: onSubmit = async(event) =>{
     event.preventDefault();
     this.setState({loading: true, errorMessage: ''});

     try{
     const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
     await factory.methods.createCampaign(this.state.minimumContribution)
     .send({
       from: accounts[0]
     });
     //we want to redirect our user to the campaignIndex, root route: /
     Router.pushRoute('/');
   }catch(err){
     this.setState({errorMessage: err.message });
   }
   this.setState({loading: false})
  };
  render(){

Comment: Put it into original question, please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are providing a `from` parameter when executing the `send` function. In that case, make sure the node you are using has accounts already created, and those accounts have funds.

If you are using [ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) it all should be ready out of the box. Otherwise you're probably using [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) in a testnet. In that case you must create an account there and send some ether through a faucet (or real ether if on mainnet).